# installing mysql gem on rbenv

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, vagrant

I'm trying to use vagrant on my MAC OSX machine. I connected vagrant with using SSH and I set ruby 1.9.2-p290. Now I'm try to install ruby gems but I've been facing with this problem when I want to install mysql2 gem.

```
Fetching: mysql-2.8.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

I set in Gem file

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

and again I run bundle command but the result is the same.

Why doesn't mysql run on vagrant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql2 gem has native C extensions that build against mysql binaries.
Your vagrant machine needs to have mysql installed.
Do something like this

```
$ vagrant ssh
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

After mysql is installed, you should be able to install the mysql2 gem.

EDIT: you also need the mysql development libraries so

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient16 ruby-dev
```